# Why using boolean operators returns less results in Gmail filters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

While trying to combine to Gmail filters, I noticed something strange: filter `from:person@example1.com` alone returns 180 results, filter `from:person@example2.com` alone returns 69 results, but when combined—`from:person@example1.com OR from:person@example2.com`—, the filter returns only 120 results. Why?

Comment: For me, using `OR`, it returns the same number of results as the search for person2. Internal algorithm issues.

Answer (score 4):

Did you validate the actual numbers? The count of results is an *estimate*, indicated by the word "about". In the version of Gmail I see today, for a search like your first one, I get:

> **1 to 20** of about **192**

But when I page through the results clicking the `>` button, the counts change:

> **21 to 40** of **many** ... **41 to 60** of **many** ... **61 to 80** of about **172** ...

If I keep paging through, I arrive at the precise number:

> **221-238** of **238**

It seems logical to me that combining another search with `OR` might give a lower number than both separately, since they're estimates.

---

Another explanation assuming result numbers are precise: the search hits are on **message threads**. It's possible that a thread can contain messages `from:user1@example.com AND from:user2@example.com` -- can you check that angle?

Comment: The results were without “of about”, so not estimates.

Comment: Gmail evolves all the time - what do you get today? That is, who's to say they weren't estimates? Did you validate the actual numbers?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I don’t know what I would get today, as I don’t remember the searches I made at that time.

Comment: The only precise numbers (without "about" or "of many") on the searches I get today are when there is less than a page (less than 20) of results. I'll make a theory that Gmail added "about" recently to the results message to resolve the inconsistency you found.

Comment: I just checked it with two different strings and for the first one I get 2 results, for the second one I get 9 results, and for both of them (`OR`) I get 12 results.

Comment: OK, do it with `( AND )` -- my guess is that some of the threads contain messages `from:` both addresses (I updated my answer at the bottom).

Comment: No, they don’t, I just checked. Besides, I’m not trying to exclude some emails, but on the contrary, I’m trying to include more—thus the use of `OR`.